# android multiple activity declaration in manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a main activity. From it, I am calling 2 other sub activities called FacebookLogin and Twitterlogin. I am using the following code in AndroidManufest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.examples.Kikin" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<!-- THIS IS THE BEGINNING OF SHARING LINKS FROM THE BROWSER -->
<application android:icon="@drawable/kikinlogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".Kikin" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FacebookLogin" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!--    <data android:mimeType="image/png" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TwitterLogin" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="yourapp" android:host="twitt"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Am i doing it right?
Should i nest the FacebookLogin and TwitterLogin activities in the main  activity?
The aforesaid 2 classes are in the package com.examples..
***** is the same wherever used.

Comment: I'll let you know what all I tried. I have tried nesting the 2 activities in the main activity. I have tried as it is given above. I am getting the runtime exception in Logcat: Have you declared this activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Is using the same label for the 3 different activities wrong? I have changed it and tried. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you post the <manifest> section, please?

Comment: When do you get this error? As soon as you start your main activity, or when you try to launch TwitterLogin or FacebookLogin? Christopher's answer below is what you should start with.

Comment: I do not get is as soon as the main activity starts. But as soon as I try to start TwitterLogin, I get the error.

Comment: And you are absolutely certain that TwitterLogin is in the package "com.examples.Kikin"?

Comment: Yes. and I am getting the same error when I am trying to start the FacebookLogin activity. I double checked now again. It is in the same package.

Comment: I have updated the full AndroidManifest.xml class.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "subactvity". Just because you call one activity from another doesn't mean it's a "subactivity".

You can't nest activity tags in the manifest and you'd probably get a compile error if you tried.

in manifest you can set only one activity in launcher tag okay android does support multiple launcher activity.

Comment: Oh ok. I said subactivity because I am calling those two from the first one. I'm sorry about my wrong semantics. What is the problem and why is it not working ?

Comment: How am I supposed to know what the problem is?

Comment: I am asking about the syntax of the file I posted above. Whether it is right or not, is what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

The labels for your FacebookLogin and TwitterLogin appear to be missing an '@' - change them to android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: good point. I changed it. am still getting the same runtime exception in Logcat.

Comment: I presume it also includes the closing </manifest> tag? Post a copy of your exception.

Comment: OK, reading between the lines I think you have the following classes: com.examples.FacebookLogin and com.examples.TwitterLogin and com.examples.Kikin - if this is the case, then change the package attribute in the root mainfest element to package="com.examples"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The 3 activity classes are : com.examples.Kikin.Kikin , com.examples.Kikin.FacebookLogin , com.examples.Kikin.TwitterLogin. So the package attribute should be com.examples.Kikin.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest you posted looked fine.

But regarding your comment about the error message "Have you declared this activity in AndroidManifest.xml?", you need to check carefully the package and class name of the `Activity` you are trying to launch, and make sure that it matches the `<activity android:name>` you have written in the manifest.

All the info you need should be in the error message.

Comment: the names are same. However I have included the Facebook.java and TwitterLogin.java classes in the package com.examples.*****. So should the name of the classes be *****.FacebookLogin ????

Comment: According to your comment, the names are **not** the same. You just said you have `Facebook.java` (implying the full class name is `com.examples.Kikin.Facebook`), yet your manifest refers to `.FacebookLogin`.  Change that to `.Facebook` (or rename the class to `FacebookLogin`).

Comment: I am sorry. I meant FacebookLogin.java.

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest activity declarations, just have them all as elements in your application element:

```
<manifest ...
  <application ...
    <activity ...
    </activity>
    <activity ...
    </activity>
    <activity ...
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

The sample you posted here (indenting aside) looks fine.

Comment: I have changed the indenting. I have not nested the activities now. Still getting the aforesaid error. any insights?

Comment: This sounds silly, but is the name of the activity correct?  android:name is relative to the package declared in the package attribute of the manifest object, is the composed full name of your activity correct?

Comment: All three classes are in the same package. So, they should be as they are written above only I guess.

Comment: So, that manifest would be right if your three activities were com.examples.Kikin.Kikin, com.examples.Kikin.FacebookLogin and com.examples.Kikin.TwitterLogin.

Comment: Yeah. Those are my 3 activities.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have tested it already but just try declaring your activities with the full path (although you have already declared it in the package tag). So, instead of using

```
<activity android:name=".TwitterLogin"  />
```

use

```
<activity android:name="com.examples.Kikin.TwitterLogin" />
```

Sometimes problems are caused because of that.

I know this is an old thread but I`m having the same problem and in my case specifying full package name doesn`t help. Have you already found a solution? I`m really interested in knowing how to avoid this error.